# Column indicating previous month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I created a filter that filters me on the last month, if I am in the last month the value da date_months is equal to "YES" otherwise the value is "NO".

```
date_Month =
VAR currentrowdate =
    FORMAT ( dimension_calendar[full_date], "mmyyyy" )
VAR month =
    FORMAT ( NOW (), "mmyyyy" )
VAR day =
    FORMAT ( NOW (), "dd" )
VAR last_month = dimension_calendar[actual_date] - 1
RETURN
    IF ( month = currentrowdate, "Yes", "No" )
```

[image: 1]

then I wanted to add a condition that if I am in the first of the month that is to say the 01 of each month I take into account the previous month .

I did this, but it doesn’t work

```
date_Month =
VAR currentrowdate =
    FORMAT ( dimension_calendar[full_date], "mmyyyy" )
VAR month =
    FORMAT ( NOW (), "mmyyyy" )
VAR day =
    FORMAT ( NOW (), "dd" )
VAR last_month = dimension_calendar[actual_date] - 1
RETURN
    IF (
        day = 01,
        AND ( "No", month = last_month ),
        IF ( month = currentrowdate, "Yes", "No" )
    )
```

you will have proposals? thank you

I wanted to add a condition that if I am in the first of the month that is to say the 01 of each month I take into account the previous month .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Previous Month = 
IF( MONTH('Table'[Date] -1) = MONTH(TODAY()) - 1, "YES", "NO")
```

[image]